# Why does the MESH token is stated to be vulnerable on the recent overflow bug of some ERC20 contract?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, vulnerability

Has you know, [there were a recent vulnerability which allowed creation of units for anyone in some ERC20 contracts](https://peckshield.com/2018/04/25/proxyOverflow/).

However, I’m [failing to find the stated vulnerable code for MESH](https://etherscan.io/address/0x01f2acf2914860331c1cb1a9acecda7475e06af8#code). Does it means it isn’t vulnerable in reality ?
If not what are the culprits lines ? **Please give an example of how the vulnerability can be triggered !**

```
// Abstract contract for the full ERC 20 Token standard
// https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract Token {
    /* This is a slight change to the ERC20 base standard.*/
    /// total amount of tokens
    uint256 public totalSupply;

    /// @param _owner The address from which the balance will be retrieved
    /// @return The balance
    function balanceOf(address _owner) public constant returns (uint256 balance);

    /// @notice send `_value` token to `_to` from `msg.sender`
    /// @param _to The address of the recipient
    /// @param _value The amount of token to be transferred
    /// @return Whether the transfer was successful or not
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success);

    /// @notice send `_value` token to `_to` from `_from` on the condition it is approved by `_from`
    /// @param _from The address of the sender
    /// @param _to The address of the recipient
    /// @param _value The amount of token to be transferred
    /// @return Whether the transfer was successful or not
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success);

    /// @notice `msg.sender` approves `_spender` to spend `_value` tokens
    /// @param _spender The address of the account able to transfer the tokens
    /// @param _value The amount of tokens to be approved for transfer
    /// @return Whether the approval was successful or not
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success);

    /// @param _owner The address of the account owning tokens
    /// @param _spender The address of the account able to transfer the tokens
    /// @return Amount of remaining tokens allowed to spent
    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public constant returns (uint256 remaining);

    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);
    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);
}

contract Owned {

    /// `owner` is the only address that can call a function with this
    /// modifier
    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    address public owner;

    /// @notice The Constructor assigns the message sender to be `owner`
    function Owned() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    address newOwner=0x0;

    event OwnerUpdate(address _prevOwner, address _newOwner);

    ///change the owner
    function changeOwner(address _newOwner) public onlyOwner {
        require(_newOwner != owner);
        newOwner = _newOwner;
    }

    /// accept the ownership
    function acceptOwnership() public{
        require(msg.sender == newOwner);
        OwnerUpdate(owner, newOwner);
        owner = newOwner;
        newOwner = 0x0;
    }
}

contract Controlled is Owned{

    function Controlled() public {
       setExclude(msg.sender);
    }

    // Flag that determines if the token is transferable or not.
    bool public transferEnabled = false;

    // flag that makes locked address effect
    bool lockFlag=true;
    mapping(address => bool) locked;
    mapping(address => bool) exclude;

    function enableTransfer(bool _enable) public onlyOwner{
        transferEnabled=_enable;
    }

    function disableLock(bool _enable) public onlyOwner returns (bool success){
        lockFlag=_enable;
        return true;
    }

    function addLock(address _addr) public onlyOwner returns (bool success){
        require(_addr!=msg.sender);
        locked[_addr]=true;
        return true;
    }

    function setExclude(address _addr) public onlyOwner returns (bool success){
        exclude[_addr]=true;
        return true;
    }

    function removeLock(address _addr) public onlyOwner returns (bool success){
        locked[_addr]=false;
        return true;
    }

    modifier transferAllowed(address _addr) {
        if (!exclude[_addr]) {
            assert(transferEnabled);
            if(lockFlag){
                assert(!locked[_addr]);
            }
        }

        _;
    }

}

contract StandardToken is Token,Controlled {

    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public transferAllowed(msg.sender) returns (bool success) {
        //Default assumes totalSupply can't be over max (2^256 - 1).
        //If your token leaves out totalSupply and can issue more tokens as time goes on, you need to check if it doesn't wrap.
        //Replace the if with this one instead.
        if (balances[msg.sender] >= _value && balances[_to] + _value > balances[_to]) {
            balances[msg.sender] -= _value;
            balances[_to] += _value;
            Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
            return true;
        } else { return false; }
    }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public transferAllowed(_from) returns (bool success) {
        //same as above. Replace this line with the following if you want to protect against wrapping uints.
        if (balances[_from] >= _value && allowed[_from][msg.sender] >= _value && balances[_to] + _value > balances[_to]) {
            balances[_to] += _value;
            balances[_from] -= _value;
            allowed[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
            Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
            return true;
        } else { return false; }
    }

    function balanceOf(address _owner) public constant returns (uint256 balance) {
        return balances[_owner];
    }

    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public constant returns (uint256 remaining) {
      return allowed[_owner][_spender];
    }

    mapping (address => uint256) balances;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) allowed;
}

contract MESH is StandardToken {

    function () public {
        revert();
    }

    string public name = "M2C Mesh Network";
    uint8 public decimals = 18;
    string public symbol = "mesh";


    // The nonce for avoid transfer replay attacks
    mapping(address => uint256) nonces;

    function MESH (uint256 initialSupply) public {
        totalSupply = initialSupply * 10 ** uint256(decimals);
        balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
    }
    /*
     * Proxy transfer token. When some users of the ethereum account has no ether,
     * he or she can authorize the agent for broadcast transactions, and agents may charge agency fees
     * @param _from
     * @param _to
     * @param _value
     * @param fee
     * @param _v
     * @param _r
     * @param _s
     */
    function transferProxy(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value, uint256 _fee,
        uint8 _v,bytes32 _r, bytes32 _s) public transferAllowed(_from) returns (bool){

        if(balances[_from] < _fee + _value) revert();

        uint256 nonce = nonces[_from];
        bytes32 h = keccak256(_from,_to,_value,_fee,nonce);
        if(_from != ecrecover(h,_v,_r,_s)) revert();

        if(balances[_to] + _value < balances[_to]
            || balances[msg.sender] + _fee < balances[msg.sender]) revert();
        balances[_to] += _value;
        Transfer(_from, _to, _value);

        balances[msg.sender] += _fee;
        Transfer(_from, msg.sender, _fee);

        balances[_from] -= _value + _fee;
        nonces[_from] = nonce + 1;
        return true;
    }

    /*
     * Proxy approve that some one can authorize the agent for broadcast transaction
     * which call approve method, and agents may charge agency fees
     * @param _from The address which should tranfer tokens to others
     * @param _spender The spender who allowed by _from
     * @param _value The value that should be tranfered.
     * @param _v
     * @param _r
     * @param _s
     */
    function approveProxy(address _from, address _spender, uint256 _value,
        uint8 _v,bytes32 _r, bytes32 _s) public returns (bool success) {

        uint256 nonce = nonces[_from];
        bytes32 hash = keccak256(_from,_spender,_value,nonce);
        if(_from != ecrecover(hash,_v,_r,_s)) revert();
        allowed[_from][_spender] = _value;
        Approval(_from, _spender, _value);
        nonces[_from] = nonce + 1;
        return true;
    }


    /*
     * Get the nonce
     * @param _addr
     */
    function getNonce(address _addr) public constant returns (uint256){
        return nonces[_addr];
    }

    /* Approves and then calls the receiving contract */
    function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes _extraData) public returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);

        //call the receiveApproval function on the contract you want to be notified. This crafts the function signature manually so one doesn't have to include a contract in here just for this.
        //receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _tokenContract, bytes _extraData)
        //it is assumed that when does this that the call *should* succeed, otherwise one would use vanilla approve instead.
        if(!_spender.call(bytes4(bytes32(keccak256("receiveApproval(address,uint256,address,bytes)"))), msg.sender, _value, this, _extraData)) { revert(); }
        return true;
    }

    /* Approves and then calls the contract code*/
    function approveAndCallcode(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes _extraData) public returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);

        //Call the contract code
        if(!_spender.call(_extraData)) { revert(); }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I thought `transferProxy` could provide the answer, but

```
        bytes32 h = keccak256(_from,_to,_value,_fee,nonce);
        if(_from != ecrecover(h,_v,_r,_s)) revert();
```

seems to make sure that such bug cannot happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `transferProxy` fucntion, `if(balances[_from] < _fee + _value) revert();` can cause overflow error. They didn't check `_fee + _value` is less than `2^256`. So when you set REALLY big number on `_value`, then `_fee + _value`, the sums up to 0 in 256 bit, so `balances[_from]` check will be passed!! 
There nothing wrong with signature verification, it has problem in checking balance of the token with the address, `_from`.

Comment: Ok. More generally, which parameters I should set for getting verification to succeed ?

Comment: @user2284570 Try with `_value = 2**256 - 1` and  `_fee = 1`.

Comment: @Ismael how do I encode them?

Comment: @user2284570 You can actually check the transaction cause the actual overflow, see https://etherscan.io/tx/0x1abab4c8db9a30e703114528e31dee129a3a758f7f8abc3b6494aad3d304e43f

Answer (score 0):

It's there, on line 209 in the code on Etherscan page you provided. I'd say this contract is indeed vulnerable.

Comment: In that case, please also explain parameters values (or give an example). Because for me, `_s` `_r` `_v` prevent the overflow to happen.