# How to use ecrecover() and what it is?

Tags: solidity, erc-20

It’s a simple question, but I couldn’t find an answer. In [an ERC20 contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/49248/25002) lies this code

```
//The nonce for avoid transfer replay attacks
mapping(address => uint256) nonces;
```

.

```
    uint256 nonce = nonces[_address_from];
    bytes32 h = keccak256(_address_from ,_address_to ,_token_amount, _amount_fee ,nonce);
    if(_address_from != ecrecover(h,_v,_r,_s)) revert();
```

`_r` `_s` `_v` are functions parameters which must be set manually when calling it on contract execution.

How do I compute `_r` `_s` `_v` from my address and amounts in order to not get the transaction rejected ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

r, s and v are obtained from the signature of the transaction. if you have the signature (assume it is in a variable called sig) you can do:

```
r = sig.signature.slice(0, 32)
s = sig.signature.slice(32, 64)
v = sig.recovery + 27
```

So if you want to check that a message was signed by an account you need to pass the r,s and v values to your contract. Notice that when you send transactions to the network, the network do the verification automatically.

The signature can be obtained with web3, see [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-personal.html#ecrecover)

Also for a complete discussion see this [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2256/ethereum-ecrecover-signature-verification-and-encryption)

Hope this help.

Comment: How do I compute transaction signature?

Comment: The link in the answer shows how to do it using web3.

Comment: No sorry. I mean how do I compute the called signature requiring for computing ecrecover parameters.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand. Maybe a bit of context in the question, indicating what you are doing, will make easy for me to provide more help. Let me know.

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/49299/25002 I [now found the function](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsign). The problem is `keccak256` and the nonce.

Comment: So you have the values `r`, `s`, and `v` from the function in web3 that is used to sign the transaction. The nonce is provided by the mapping variable `nonce` for each particular address. So you can now check the signature. You seem to be ok now.

Comment: the nonce value is computed on contract execution side. I don’t have it on the caller/client side.