# How to compute ecrecover parameters in solidity?

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-20, ecrecover

There are many answer which explain how to compute `_r`, `_s`, `_v` with an other language.
But how to compute parameters in solidity itself ? Is there a built-in function like `ecrecover` ?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but why would you want to do this?

Comment: @EdmundEdgar I´m [having really a hard time](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/15911/25002) at [doing it with web3](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/49299/25002). Converting hex values to a binary form usable by web3 is an example. I think I need to find a way at doing it with solidity since I'm unable to get the exact code.

Answer (score 1):

Computing the `v`, `r`, `s` inputs to `ecrecover` is another way of saying "create a signature". Normally you wouldn't want to do this in Solidity, as it would imply that the private key was recoverable from the blockchain, and private keys aren't usually useful unless they're private.

Accordingly, Solidity has no built-in function to sign data. I'm not sure if anyone has written a library to do this, and I can't imagine what it would be useful for, but in principle it should be possible.

Comment: I’m forced to use solidity because [I cannot modify the smart contract in order to get it working with web3js](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/15911/25002)